# How do I get the id of a HTML element in my custom element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling, custom-element

My custom element looks like this:

```
class item extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('id', 'btn')
    button.textContent = "click here";

    shadow.appendChild(button);
}
```

I'm trying to create a DOM event listener to detect the button click in another JS file, so far my code there looks like this:

```
document.querySelector("item").root.querySelector('#cart').addEventListener("click", function({...});
```

I'm stuck on the document.querySelector area to listen to the button click in the custom element "item"

This is how I declare it, I basically append the custom element to a ul element:

HTML snippet:

```
<ul class="flex-container" id="list"></ul>
```

JS snippet:

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("ON LOAD");

    product = document.createElement('item');

    let fcontain = document.getElementById("list");

    fcontain.appendChild(product);

};
```

Comment: Could you show us a complete snippet including the HTML so we can see what your structure is. At the moment I can’t understand what the .root part of your selecting is doing.

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with HTML to be honest. I just appended it to a ul item.

HTML snippet: <ul class="flex-container" id="product-list"></ul>

JS snippet:
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("ON LOAD");

  product = document.createElement('item');

  let fcontain = document.getElementById("list");

  fcontain.appendChild(product);

};

Comment: Sorry, just updated my post now

Comment: Custom Elements **must have** a hyphen **-** in the nodeName, so your ``item`` is **not** a Custom Element; it will be an Unknown Element without Custom Element behavior. And ``.root.`` must be ``.shadowRoot.`` And there is no Element with ``#cart`` in your code. Learn to include [running Code Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and you will definitely get more help.